# Change font-size within a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I have a simple shortcode like this....

```
function myshortcode( $attributes, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => ''
    ), $attributes ) );
           return 'This is the content : ' . $content . ';
}
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'myshortcode');
```

This works great and if I use the following in a post...

```
[my_shortcode]This is the content that I want to display[/my_shortcode]
```

But what I want to do now is vary the font size of the content for example...

```
[my_shortcode]This is the [25px]content[/25px] that I want to display[/my_shortcode]
```

I want this to change the word 'content' to 25px font size.

Anyone know a way, maybe str_replace?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to put a shortcode within a shortcode? Perhaps this is an easier solution to control your front-end output?

CSS

```
span.my_pixel_size{font-size:25px;}
```

PHP

```
'<p>This is the content: <span class="my_pixel_size">' . $content . '</span></p>';
```

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of shortcodes, you would need to create a shortcode for each pixel. It would be much easier to define a single shortcode, then use attributes to define a font-size.

```
function font_callback( $attributes, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'size'  => '12px'
    ), $attributes ) );

    return '<span style="font-size:' . $size . '">' . $content . '</span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'font', 'font_callback' );
```

Then you can say something like:

```
This is the [font size="18px"]content[/font] that I want to display
```

This of course could be expanded upon to include `font-family`, `classes`, and an `id`.